# What is git-repo init and git-repo sync?

Tags: git, repository, repo

I'm using Google's [git-repo](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) plugin. According to my understanding `repo sync` will download the whole source code (i.e. previous revisions) from the repository. That is why it is taking a lot of time to complete this whole process.

Can we download only the latest commit from the repository?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "repo sync"? That isn't a git command.

Comment: @AD7six He's talking about the tool Google made to help manage Android.  [Repo](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) is built on top of Git.

Comment: @jszakmeister thanks for clarifying. The tags `git` and `github` alone were quite misleading - arguably they still are, as a git-answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AD7six you'll see questions regarding git-repo pop up every now and again.

Answer (score 5):

I don't use repo, but it appears that you can [pass the `--depth` flag](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/source/browse/repo?name=bca94fd1b0#125) to `repo init`.  Using something like `repo init -u URL --depth=1`.  The depth flag gets passed to [`git-clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) and create a repo with only part of the history:

> `--depth <depth>`
>
> Create a **shallow** clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions. A shallow repository has a number of
> limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into
> it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history
> of a large project with a long history, and would want to send in
> fixes as patches.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by default `git fetch` (which is part of what `git clone` does) will fetch 
the complete history of the remote repository.

You can limit the amount of history that is retrieved by using the `--depth` 
option of the fetch command (clone will pass that on to fetch). To retrieve the 
minimal amount of history you could use:

```
git clone --depth 1 REPO_URL
```

This would retrieve the latest commit and the one(s) immediately preceding it, 
but not older commits. It isn't possible to retrieve just the latest commit, 
since a depth of 0 is taken as wanting the full history; but this is close.

Later you can use `git fetch` with a larger depth to increase the amount of 
available history, or use `git fetch --unshallow` to retrieve the complete 
history.

There are currently a number of limitations on shallow repositories.  The 
[docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) for `git clone --depth` say:

> A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch 
>   from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only 
>   interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and 
>   would want to send in fixes as patches.

Although there has recently been work on reducing or perhaps even removing 
those limitations.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably `git pull`
See [the docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html). You first need to add your github repository as a remote host:

```
git remote add master git@github.com:username/repository.git
```

Afterwards you can pull from the repository. On github there is also a link to download any commit as a `.zip` file. Format for that is usually:

```
https://github.com/username/repository/archive/master.zip
```